# Typescript:Type 'Ivalue[T]' cannot be used to index type '{ '1': number; '2': number; '3': number; }'

Tags: typescript

I have a demo in [typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwjAvDA3gKBpmBZAogFQAkB5AEQC5UMsaByARlsoCYAaamzW5pmNjzrQDMvIQIC+7GnDgBlAJIBxAHIAxADIBBRZXScstACy9DU-TFoBWXpbP7aANl4OJacQG40ASzBQApgBOAGYAhsB+MPIA0n4AnlQ0ALZ+UAAWIAAmlAzMQvS5+SKeNMDAsl4A5mCqADYhFdnMTTzFWADaANZxlNABPhUAuj1QfWAVnuLevoGh4ZEAbiE1AK4ReljJaZnZjDAAPhY8+xZFAqXlVbX12cbHVrR3Tq2Ynd0wvf1D7yP9E2hoQWWYGAUC84Bg-mgAB58DA-AAPfxgDIQGBdWIgIKRGKxAB8AAogl4-DUsjB8KwYIsVn5KPJqas2vgBgBKBJYCAAdy8UGAqRghOJpLZ630wBCEAitE26QyTAE5hgARSywCYHgbVoeCIZFoAzaDL8A2eMEmk0hUHxtHOlWqdQqtEpRloLM8QA)

```
const C = {
    METHOD: {
        '1': 2,
        '2': 2,
        '3': 3
    },
    CCSIGNFLAG: {
        '4': 4,
        '5': 5,
        '6': 6
    }
};
interface IKey {
    method: '123123123';
    ccSignFlag: '2222';
    [key: string]: string;
}
interface Ivalue {
    method: '1' | '2' | '3';
    ccSignFlag: '4' | '5' | '6';
    [key: string]: string;
}

function test<T extends keyof IKey>(field: T, value: Ivalue[T]) {
    switch (field) {
        case 'method':
            return C['METHOD'][value];
    }
}
test('ccSignFlag', '4');
```

show error:`Type 'Ivalue[T]' cannot be used to index type '{ '1': number; '2': number; '3': number; }'`

I want the first argument to constrain the input of the second argument

what should i do?

Comment: what do you mean with the *input* of the second value?

Comment: First parameter as key value constraint second parameter,

The first parameter is passed in 'method',
The second parameter is restricted to Ivalue ['method'] can only pass in '4' | '5' | '6'

Comment: Can you provide some valid and invalid parameters examples for ```test```?

Comment: `test ('method', '4')` is invalid, because the first parameter is `method` and the second parameter is of type `Ivalue['method']`, which is **'1' | '2' | '3'**

Comment: I have more questions: what's the purpose of ```IKey```? (it looks like you can do everything with just ```Ivalue```. What's the purpose of the code inside ```test(...)```?

Comment: Yes,you are right! But it doesn't seem to solve my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I found [a solution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAwjAvDA3gKBpmBZAogFQAkB5AEQC5UMsaByARlsoCYAaamzW5pmNjzrQDMvIQIC+7GnDgBlAJIBxAHIAxADIBBRZXScstACy9DU-TFoBWXpbP7aANl4OJacQG40ASzBQApgBOAGYAhsB+MPIA0n4AnlQ0ALZ+UAAWIAAmlAzMQvS5+SKeNMDAsl4A5mCqADYhFdnMTTzFWADaANZxlNABPhUAuj1QfWAVnuLevoGh4ZEAbiE1AK4ReljJaZnZjDAAPhY8+xZFAqXlVbX12cbHVrR3Tq2Ynd0wvf1D7yP9E2hoQWWYGAUC84Bg-mgAB58DA-AAPfxgDIQGBdWIgIKRGKxAB8AAogl4-DUsjB8KwYIsVn5KPJqas2vgBgBKBJYCAAdy8UGAqRghOJpLZ630wBCEAitE26QyTAE5hgARSywCYHgbVoeCIZFoAzaDIiErRcUxENiAAc-Ga4JrtSRSHqBs8xRKpedKtU6hV5YqaMqoKr1bbaDIFCoNNo9QalqsYMb0WaoJbrViQ2GlGotIonQqsBk-KFljUoOQ8-oA0GqbG-C7JpNIVB8bQPZdvbRKUZaCzPEA)
But I don't think that's the best solution
Is there any other way?

```
const C = {
    METHOD: {
        '1': 2,
        '2': 2,
        '3': 3
    },
    CCSIGNFLAG: {
        '4': 4,
        '5': 5,
        '6': 6
    }
};
interface IKey {
    method: '123123123';
    ccSignFlag: '2222';
    [key: string]: string;
}
interface Ivalue {
    method: '1' | '2' | '3';
    ccSignFlag: '4' | '5' | '6';
    [key: string]: string;
}

function test<T extends keyof IKey>(field: T, value: Ivalue[T]) {
    switch (field) {
        case 'method':
            //                       ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
            return C['METHOD'][value as keyof typeof C['METHOD']];
         case 'ccSignFlag':
            //                           ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
            return C['CCSIGNFLAG'][value as keyof typeof C['CCSIGNFLAG']]
        default:
            return value;
    }
}
test('ccSignFlag', '4');
```